# Python, google colab

Tags: python

```
x=str(input('Where to'))
y=str(input('Which uber'))

if x == ('Cleveland'):
  print('400 miles')
if x == ('Detriot'):
  print('500 miles')
if x == ('Sandusky'):
  print('100 miles')
if x == ('Lakewood'):
  print('200 miles')
if x == ('Rocky River'):
    print('550 miles')
elif x == ('none'):
      print(compares)
compares = x * y
```

Question: if i made the user type in a new value for x how i would multiply that by the y they gave?

Comment: What do you mean by `the number I get from x and y`? The mile numbers you are printing? Right now x and y contain a city and `which uber`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour (stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the help center (stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how do you multiply `x and y` are strings?

Comment: yeah so if i typed in none for my location and made them type in their own number how i would i mulipply the new number they choose by the y value they choose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary

> Note: by default `input()` returns string no need to convert it into string.

```
x = input('Where to: ')
y = input('Which uber: ')
cities = {'Cleveland': 400, 'Detriot': 500, 'Sandusky': 100, 'Lakewood': 200, 'Rocky River': 550}

if x in cities and y in cities:
    compares = cities[x] * cities[y]
    print(compares)
else:
    print('Select valid location')
```